# AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call

Tags: python, pytorch

I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 63, in <module>
    question_classifier = QuestionClassifier(corpus.dictionary, embeddings_index, corpus.max_sent_length, args)
  File "/net/if5/wua4nw/wasi/academic/research_with_prof_chang/projects/question_answering/duplicate_question_detection/source/question_classifier.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.embedding = EmbeddingLayer(len(dictionary), args.emsize, args.dropout)
  File "/if5/wua4nw/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 255, in __setattr__
    "cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call")
AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call
```

I have a class as follows.

```
class QuestionClassifier(nn.Module):

     def __init__(self, dictionary, embeddings_index, max_seq_length, args):
         self.embedding = EmbeddingLayer(len(dictionary), args.emsize, args.dropout)
         self.encoder = EncoderRNN(args.emsize, args.nhid, args.model, args.bidirection, args.nlayers, args.dropout)
         self.drop = nn.Dropout(args.dropout)
```

So, when I run the following line:

```
question_classifier = QuestionClassifier(corpus.dictionary, embeddings_index, corpus.max_sent_length, args)
```

I get the above mentioned error. Here, `EmbeddingLayer` and `EncoderRNN` is a class written by me which inherits `nn.module` like the `QuestionClassifier` class.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have posted it. I believe I am missing something but can't figure out what!!

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `torch`, but perhaps you have to call `nn.Module.__init__()` inside your derived classes `__init__` before you can modify any attributes...

Comment: I am doing that actually!!

Comment: In your code? Before you assign to an attribute? I don't see where...

Comment: did you try `would `super().__init__()` ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Looking at the `pytorch` [source code for `Module`](http://pytorch.org/docs/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html), we see in the docstring an example of deriving from `Module` includes:

```
 class Model(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Model, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)
```

So you probably want to call `Module`'s init the same way in your derived class:

```
super(QuestionClassifier, self).__init__()
```

Comment: would `super().__init__()` work?

Comment: @CharlieParker yes, those would be equivalent (unless, for some reason, you are still on Python 2)

Answer (score 7):

This usually happens when super class's init has not been called. In this case one should start their Neural network class with **super.__init__() call**. The code would look like this:

```
class QuestionClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dictionary, embeddings_index, max_seq_length, args):
       super().__init__()
```

This super's init call should be within this class's init code.

Comment: would `super().__init__()` work?

Answer (score 6):

Pytorch keeps track of the submodules(`conv1`, `conv2`) you will write in your custom Module. Under the hood, the graph corresponding to your Model is automatically built.

The nested Modules will be added to an OrderedDict `_modules` (initialized in `nn.Module.__init__`) See [source(L69)](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L69)

If `nn.Module.__init__` is not called (`self._modules` would equal to `None`), when trying to add a Module, it will raise an error (no key can be added to `None`). See
[source(L540-544)](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/eb02a1d8a7c51b26456cb28229612ff6fe17ed5e/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L540-L544)

Inspired from the [doc](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/eb02a1d8a7c51b26456cb28229612ff6fe17ed5e/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L34-L38):

```
 class CustomModule(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(CustomModule, self).__init__() # Initialize self._modules as OrderedDict
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)     # Add key conv1 to self._modules
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)    # Add key conv2 to self._modules
```

Comment: would `super().__init__()` work?