# Error: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call, Even after using super(DecoderRNN, self).__init__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am receiving following error:

```
AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call
```

Although, this error has been resolved in

[AttributeError: cannot assign module before Module.__init__() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080583/attributeerror-cannot-assign-module-before-module-init-call)

through the inclusion of `super().__init__()` method in the class, I continue receiving the same error even after using the proposed solution.

Following is the class that I have developed:

```
class DecoderRNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, embed_size, hidden_size, vocab_size, num_layers=1):
    super(DecoderRNN, self).__init__()
    self.embed_size = embed_size
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
    self.embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size)
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first = True)
```

Comment: This might simply be an error while pasting code, but looks like the indentation is off from the second line onwards

Comment: Actually the problem got solved once I restarted the editor. Not sure why it happed though.